# Sort coreData base on NSDate ascending not working

Tags: swift, sorting, core-data, nsdate

I try to sort coreData result base on NSDate ascending true but not working.

here is my code:

```
let activityPredicateCompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .and, subpredicates: [exampleIdKeyPredicate,userIdKeyPredicate])
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nsDate", ascending: true)
fetchRequestActivity.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
fetchRequestActivity.fetchLimit = 10
fetchRequestActivity.predicate = activityPredicateCompound
let activities = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequestActivity)
```

and then

```
for activity in activities {
print("activity nsDate:\(activity.value(forKey: "nsDate") as! NSDate)")}
```

print result are  (true or false):

```
activity nsDate:2018-12-15 02:15:00 +0000
activity nsDate:2018-12-13 09:45:00 +0000
```

I want result like this :

```
activity nsDate:2018-12-13 09:45:00 +0000
activity nsDate:2018-12-15 02:15:00 +0000
```

What is the correct code to do that?

Comment: Could you check what happen when you change to  `let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nsDate", ascending: false)` ?

Comment: It is also same order, updated in question

Comment: It is weird! I've just tried your code and it worked. If ascending is true, it should work.

Comment: @Ahmet, in my case, even true or false it show the same.